# BMI Calculator in C programming... Cant run?

Tags: c, error-handling, calculator

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float h,w,x;
    printf("Enter your height and weight");
    scanf("%f %f",&h,&w);
    w/(h*h)==x;
    scanf("%f",&x);
    if(x<=18.5)
    {printf("You are UNDER WEIGHT");
    }
    else if("x==(18.5&&24.9)")
    {printf("You are AVERAGE");
    }
    else if("x>=(25&&29.9)")
    {printf("You are OVER WEIGHT");
    }
    else
    {printf("OBESITY!!!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm a beginner in programming. I wanted to do a complex program using nested if else statement. But I can't execute the the above code. Can you help me ? ***Sorry for my noobness***. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: @AngularLover: `u`? `ur`? If you can't take the time to type out the `yo` as well, then you're obviously too busy to be on this site...

Comment: What is this: `w/(h*h)==x;` ???

Comment: thats W divided by H square!

Comment: But the result of the expression is never used. And please explain what you mean by "I can't execute the above code."

Comment: @VijayBoopathy On the left. And what is on the right? And what do you expect this line to do?

Comment: That carries the value of that formula i.e value of w/h*H is x

Comment: It carries it nowhere.

Comment: Carries where? When you have a calculation, usually you want to have it's result somewhere.

Comment: Why not? I dont understand!

Comment: Your code compiles and runs. The compiler gives me a warning about the aforementioned `w/(h*h)==x` being a statement with no effect, and the result is nonsensical. But it does compile and run.

Comment: the formula is w/h*h. I want to store the value in x. what should I do?

Comment: Ok, I see a total lack of basic syntax knowledge here. Maybe you should open some books. To have a value of the formula in `x`, you have to write `x=w/(h*h);`. But it won't have much effect, since in the next line you are overwriting `x` with `scanf`, so you program doesn't make any sense in this form.

Comment: If I want to run that formula what should I do?

Comment: I want to ask another thing

Comment: Is this "x>=(25&&29.9)" correct.

Comment: What I wanted to do here is, x>=25 to 29.9

Comment: No, it is a total mess. Look at the @Cool Guy 's answer, he is showing how to make things to work. But make sure you understand your mistakes and their correction.

Comment: Sure. Thank you ! You guys are really active in this site!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
w/(h*h)==x;
scanf("%f",&x);
```

To

```
if(h) //if h is not zero
    x=w/(h*h); //calculate x
```

And these

```
else if("x==(18.5&&24.9)")
else if("x>=(25&&29.9)")
```

To

```
else if(x>18.5 && x<=24.9)
else if(x>=25 && x<=29.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line compares w/(h*h) to x.

```
w/(h*h)==x;
```

If you are trying to assign the result of the calculation to x, use this:

```
x = w/(h*h);
```

Also you need to remove the "" from the if statements and then evaluate them one at a time e.g.

```
if(x>18.5 && x<=24.9)
```